# Is there a geometric or calculus-based reason why the following system of equations should have only one solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-calculus

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4>0$. Consider the following cyclic system of equations:

$$ 2 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4  - 2 \left( \frac{x_2}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} + \frac{x_3}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} + \frac{x_4}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_4}} \right)=0,$$

$$ 2 + x_1 + x_3 + x_4 + x_1 x_3 x_4 -2 \left( \frac{x_1}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_2}} + \frac{x_3}{ \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} + \frac{x_4}{ \sqrt{x_2 x_4}} \right)=0,$$

$$ 2 + x_1 + x_2 + x_4 + x_1 x_2 x_4 -2 \left( \frac{x_1}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_3}} + \frac{x_2}{ \sqrt{x_2 x_3}} + \frac{x_4}{ \sqrt{x_3 x_4}} \right)=0,$$

$$ 2 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_3 -2 \left( \frac{x_1}{ \sqrt{x_1 x_4}} + \frac{x_2}{ \sqrt{x_2 x_4}} + \frac{x_3}{ \sqrt{x_3 x_4}} \right)=0.$$

It is long, but easy, to check that this has only one solution, namely $x_1=\dots=x_4=1$.

However, I am not looking for the solution. I am looking for a geometric or calculus-based explanation as to why such a system of equations should have only one solution.

So far, I have the following: every equation has a positive derivative with respect to at least one variable. Hence, if we start at a $0$, we cannot reach another zero by simply moving along any of the coordinate lines. This of course doesn't cover the infinite number of other paths that do not lie along coordinate lines.

Comment: "It is long, but easy, to check" ... "a geometric or calculus-based explanation" ... I am wondering what your easy solution is, and also what kind it is, if not geometric or calculus-based.

Comment: @IosifPinelis- It involves a couple of pages of computation. However, I have many higher order systems of equations like these, for which carrying out this computation would be too time-consuming. However, I know that $(1,1,1\dots,1)$ is always a solution for them. Hence, if I can find a simple argument that suggests there can only be one solution for this system of equations, I might be able to use this argument for those systems as well. Thank you

Comment: there are multiple complex solutions, I presume you want the variables to be real?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker- Yes, also strictly positive. Sorry I should have specified that, I will add that to the description.

Comment: @ChristianRemling- Haha fair enough

Comment: @ChristianRemling Wouldn't be better by 24?